# inherit and typedef(using) in one place

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, typedef

Is it possible to inherit a class and typedef it in one single place for maintainability?

```
class B{};
template<class T1,class T2> class D{};//In real case, it has 5+ parameters
template<class T2>class E: public D<B,T2> {   //duplicate D<B,T2>
    using super=D<B,T2>;                      //duplicate D<B,T2>
    //.... a lot of refererence to "super" (e.g. SNIFAE, static_assert)
};
```

I dreamed for something like :-

```
template<class T2>class F: using super= public D<B,T2> {
};
```

I am trying to avoid using macro.
So far I didn't find any question about it, but also didn't find some confirmation that it is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A better idiom for referring to base classes from derived classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846812/a-better-idiom-for-referring-to-base-classes-from-derived-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that.  But you can avoid retyping all the template arguments with

```
using super = typename E::D;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to inherit a class and typedef it in one single place for maintainability?

You can't do that without using a macro.

Don't sweat the small stuff. **This is small stuff**